# Exploring short ways in pandas to GROUPBY & JOIN without creating intermediate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

In my attempt to curtail my code, I observed I quite often need to groupby and then join the grouped dataframe to the parent one.  Are there any ways to write a more elegant and concise code? Please check my example below:

**Assume this parent dataframe:** (you can copy and paste to play around)

```
chem_1=np.array([-5, 9, -1,4,-2,3,4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,8,np.nan,9])
chem_2=np.array([6, -1, -4,np.nan,-7,-5,5,np.nan,10,-9,8,6,np.nan])
frame_total=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(chem_1,chem_2)), columns=['chem_1', 'chem_2'])
frame_total['sum_hourly']=frame_total.sum(axis=1)
frame_total.loc[frame_total[['chem_1', 'chem_2']].isnull().all(1),'sum_hourly']=np.nan
frame_total.index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=13, freq='6H')
print(frame_total)

                     chem_1  chem_2  sum_hourly
2018-01-01 00:00:00    -5.0     6.0         1.0
2018-01-01 06:00:00     9.0    -1.0         8.0
2018-01-01 12:00:00    -1.0    -4.0        -5.0
2018-01-01 18:00:00     4.0     NaN         4.0
2018-01-02 00:00:00    -2.0    -7.0        -9.0
2018-01-02 06:00:00     3.0    -5.0        -2.0
2018-01-02 12:00:00     4.0     5.0         9.0
2018-01-02 18:00:00     NaN     NaN         NaN
2018-01-03 00:00:00     NaN    10.0        10.0
2018-01-03 06:00:00     NaN    -9.0        -9.0
2018-01-03 12:00:00     8.0     8.0        16.0
2018-01-03 18:00:00     NaN     6.0         6.0
2018-01-04 00:00:00     9.0     NaN         9.0
```

**EXAMPLE:** A simple `groupby` and `join` is described below which will populate the column 'sum_24_a' that sums up the hourly sum values per calendar day. However, I recently found that I can shorten this by applying the second part of code, which populates the column 'sum_24_b'

```
# first part: create a dataframe and then join to get column 'sum_24_a'
frame_sum=frame_total.groupby(frame_total.index.date)['sum_hourly'].sum().to_frame('sum_24_a')
frame_total=frame_total.join(frame_sum)

# second part: directly create column 'sum_24_b' without the need of joining
frame_total['sum_24_b']=frame_total['sum_hourly'].groupby(frame_total.index.date).sum()

print(frame_total)

                     chem_1  chem_2  sum_hourly  sum_24_a  sum_24_b
2018-01-01 00:00:00    -5.0     6.0         1.0       8.0       8.0
2018-01-01 06:00:00     9.0    -1.0         8.0       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 12:00:00    -1.0    -4.0        -5.0       NaN       NaN
2018-01-01 18:00:00     4.0     NaN         4.0       NaN       NaN
2018-01-02 00:00:00    -2.0    -7.0        -9.0      -2.0      -2.0
2018-01-02 06:00:00     3.0    -5.0        -2.0       NaN       NaN
2018-01-02 12:00:00     4.0     5.0         9.0       NaN       NaN
2018-01-02 18:00:00     NaN     NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN
2018-01-03 00:00:00     NaN    10.0        10.0      23.0      23.0
2018-01-03 06:00:00     NaN    -9.0        -9.0       NaN       NaN
2018-01-03 12:00:00     8.0     8.0        16.0       NaN       NaN
2018-01-03 18:00:00     NaN     6.0         6.0       NaN       NaN
2018-01-04 00:00:00     9.0     NaN         9.0       9.0       9.0
```

**QUESTION:** Is there a similar suggestion to perform the following more complex GROUPBY, AGG and JOIN without needing to create the 'frame_day' dataframe and then join it to the original, as shown below?

```
frame_day=frame_total.between_time('10:00:00', '16:00:00').\
          groupby(frame_total.between_time('10:00:00', '16:00:00').index.date)['sum_hourly'].\
          agg([('sum_day', lambda x: x.sum()), \
               ('positive_sum_day', lambda x: x[x>0].sum()), \
               ('negative_sum_day', lambda x: x[x<0].sum())])
frame_total=frame_total.join(frame_day)

print(frame_total.head(8))

                     chem_1  chem_2  sum_hourly  sum_24_a  sum_24_b  \
2018-01-01 00:00:00    -5.0     6.0         1.0       8.0       8.0   
2018-01-01 06:00:00     9.0    -1.0         8.0       NaN       NaN   
2018-01-01 12:00:00    -1.0    -4.0        -5.0       NaN       NaN   
2018-01-01 18:00:00     4.0     NaN         4.0       NaN       NaN   
2018-01-02 00:00:00    -2.0    -7.0        -9.0      -2.0      -2.0   
2018-01-02 06:00:00     3.0    -5.0        -2.0       NaN       NaN   
2018-01-02 12:00:00     4.0     5.0         9.0       NaN       NaN   
2018-01-02 18:00:00     NaN     NaN         NaN       NaN       NaN   

                     sum_day  positive_sum_day  negative_sum_day  
2018-01-01 00:00:00     -5.0               0.0              -5.0  
2018-01-01 06:00:00      NaN               NaN               NaN  
2018-01-01 12:00:00      NaN               NaN               NaN  
2018-01-01 18:00:00      NaN               NaN               NaN  
2018-01-02 00:00:00      9.0               9.0               0.0  
2018-01-02 06:00:00      NaN               NaN               NaN  
2018-01-02 12:00:00      NaN               NaN               NaN  
2018-01-02 18:00:00      NaN               NaN               NaN
```

I hope my question and example are clear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: use `groupby.transform` to keep your original index

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice, I found this link (https://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html) where I could see a good example. If I manage to apply it to this dataset here, I will post it. Otherwise, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question here's a solution.   You can drop the date column later if you don't need it.

```
frame_total['date'] = frame_total.index.date
frame_total['sum_24_a'] = frame_total.groupby('date')['sum_hourly'].sum()
print(frame_total)

                     chem_1  chem_2  sum_hourly        date  sum_24_a
2018-01-01 00:00:00    -5.0     6.0         1.0  2018-01-01       8.0
2018-01-01 06:00:00     9.0    -1.0         8.0  2018-01-01       NaN
2018-01-01 12:00:00    -1.0    -4.0        -5.0  2018-01-01       NaN
2018-01-01 18:00:00     4.0     NaN         4.0  2018-01-01       NaN
2018-01-02 00:00:00    -2.0    -7.0        -9.0  2018-01-02      -2.0
2018-01-02 06:00:00     3.0    -5.0        -2.0  2018-01-02       NaN
2018-01-02 12:00:00     4.0     5.0         9.0  2018-01-02       NaN
2018-01-02 18:00:00     NaN     NaN         NaN  2018-01-02       NaN
2018-01-03 00:00:00     NaN    10.0        10.0  2018-01-03      23.0
2018-01-03 06:00:00     NaN    -9.0        -9.0  2018-01-03       NaN
2018-01-03 12:00:00     8.0     8.0        16.0  2018-01-03       NaN
2018-01-03 18:00:00     NaN     6.0         6.0  2018-01-03       NaN
2018-01-04 00:00:00     9.0     NaN         9.0  2018-01-04       9.0
```

Regarding the second question, here's a simple way to generate the 'sum_day' column. The others may be built in the same way:

```
frame_total['sum_day'] = frame_total.loc[
    frame_total.between_time('10:00:00', '16:00:00').index] \
    .groupby('date')['sum_hourly'].agg('sum')
print(frame_total.head(8))

                     chem_1  chem_2  sum_hourly        date  sum_24_a  sum_day
2018-01-01 00:00:00    -5.0     6.0         1.0  2018-01-01       8.0     -5.0
2018-01-01 06:00:00     9.0    -1.0         8.0  2018-01-01       NaN      NaN
2018-01-01 12:00:00    -1.0    -4.0        -5.0  2018-01-01       NaN      NaN
2018-01-01 18:00:00     4.0     NaN         4.0  2018-01-01       NaN      NaN
2018-01-02 00:00:00    -2.0    -7.0        -9.0  2018-01-02      -2.0      9.0
2018-01-02 06:00:00     3.0    -5.0        -2.0  2018-01-02       NaN      NaN
2018-01-02 12:00:00     4.0     5.0         9.0  2018-01-02       NaN      NaN
2018-01-02 18:00:00     NaN     NaN         NaN  2018-01-02       NaN      NaN
```